# Unable to validate user input - onkeyup event not firing

Tags: javascript

I'm getting no Javascript errors, but the code does nothing...

```
function registerValidator(target, validator) {
    var element = document.getElementById(target);
    if (element) {
        var validationID = element.id + "_validationResult";
        var validationSpan = document.createElement('span');
        validationSpan.id = validationID;

        element.parentNode.appendChild(validationSpan);

        element.onkeyup = function() {
            var result = validator(element);

            if (result.ok) {
                validationSpan.innerHTML = '<img src="/media/valid.gif" width="12" />';
            } else {
                validationSpan.innerHTML = '<img src="/media/invalid.gif" width="12" />';
                if (result.message) {
                    validationSpan.innerHTML += '<br />' + result.message;
                }
            }
        };
        alert(1);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    registerValidator('username', function(element) {
        var result = new Object();
        alert('validate');
        if (element.value.length >= 4) {
            result.ok = true;
        }
        else {
            result.ok = false;
            result.message = "Too short";
        }
        return result;
    });
    alert(2);
}
```

The two alerts (1 and 2) are triggered correctly, but the 'validate' alert is never triggered. The function is used for the following element:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
```

I have tried this in Google Chrome, Firefox 3 and Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: There has to be something else. Is there any more related code that you could post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. I forgot there's another textbox with id "username" in the header of the page, to allow people to login. Obviously the validation was working fine there ¬_¬

Answer (score 3):

Everything is working fine here. see test page at http://ashita.org/StackOverflow/validator.html

---

You are currently using element.onkeyup which could be getting clobbered by another script.

try using

```
if (element.addEventListener)
    element.addEventListener("keyup", validator,false);
else if (element.attachEvent) 
    element.attachEvent("onkeyup", validator);
```

References:

- attachEvent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx
- addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

your  element looks malformed.  Did you actually have three quotes after the id= ?

Comment: Oops, no I did not. It was an error during the copy-pasta'ing. (From removing the value part).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with the script. I have the following html working perfectly for me in IE8 and FF with your script,

```
<html>
<script>
function registerValidator(target, validator) {
    var element = document.getElementById(target);
    if (element) {
        var validationID = element.id + "_validationResult";
        var validationSpan = document.createElement('span');
        validationSpan.id = validationID;

        element.parentNode.appendChild(validationSpan);

        element.onkeyup = function() {
            var result = validator(element);

            if (result.ok) {
                validationSpan.innerHTML = '<img src="/media/valid.gif" width="12" />';
            } else {
                validationSpan.innerHTML = '<img src="/media/invalid.gif" width="12" />';
                if (result.message) {
                    validationSpan.innerHTML += '<br />' + result.message;
                }
            }
        };
        alert(1);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    registerValidator('username', function(element) {
        var result = new Object();
        alert('validate');
        if (element.value.length >= 4) {
            result.ok = true;
        }
        else {
            result.ok = false;
            result.message = "Too short";
        }
        return result;
    });
    alert(2);
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
</body>
</html>
```

There might be someother script trying to modify the onkeyup event handler for the element.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it in Chrome and IE8 locally and it works absolutely fine.  You're not setting the window.onload event elsewhere in your code are you?  What about loading other libraries like JQuery or Prototype?

If you're receiving absolutely nothing at all I'd expect that something is overriding the onload or onkeyup events.

Answer (score 0):

The onkeyup event handler function needs to take a single argument:

```
element.onkeyup = function(evt) {
```

See [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeyup).

Comment: having the event parameter is _not_ required. The browser will however _supply_ the event parameter when calling the event handler.